# Specify columns to be returned on Insert

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Given an entity like

```
class Foo
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int SometimesComputed { get; set; }
}
```

On Insert, the SQL generated will return the value for `SometimesComputed`:

```
INSERT 
...
RETURNING "SometimesComputed" INTO "SometimesComputed"
OPEN :p0 FOR SELECT "SometimesComputed" AS "SometimesComputed" FROM DUAL;
```

Which is great.  The caveat with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` or `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, however, is that any value I specify for `SometimesComputed` before inserting will be ignored and replaced with the DB computed value.

```
var foo = new Foo { SometimesComputed = 42 };
context.DbSet<Foo>().Add(foo);
context.SaveChanges();

// foo.SometimesComputed will be whatever the next sequence value was, not 42
```

Is it possible to get Entity Framework to do the `RETURNING ... INTO  OPEN FOR SELECT` regardless?  Whether I specify a value, whether it gets set by a trigger, just always return the inserted value.

Comment: I know I could always refresh the entity with the values from the database after `SaveChanges` but I'm trying to avoid a second query.

Comment: I don't get the purpose for why you want this kind of update but you can do it with stored procedure.